# Assigning realistic climate zones

Tags: internal-consistency, climate, worldbuilding-process

I'm thinking about the Koeppen climate zones for my Earth-like planet. It is all very roughly painted, because I would like to get it right first before fine-tuning the world. I've so far started with the major continent of my world, using the videos made by [Artefexian](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeh-pJYRZTBJDXMNZeWSUVA) and Wikipedia.

Please ignore the gray/white continents, they are placeholders for now. Elongated dark gray areas denote large mountain ranges.

The planet is an earth clone, orbiting a sun-like star. I have not thought about moons yet (assume an earth moon for now).

My main question is:

Are the rough climate zones for the central continent realistic?

Specifically: The central (cold) deserts and the climate within the rift valley to the right of the main central desert.

And whether I could expected a monsoon climate in the south east of the continent and the tropical islands to the east of it.

[image]

Comment: For a start, it's spelled "steppe".

Comment: Welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. Please take our [tour] and visit our [help] to better understand the site. Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum. It's model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer. This is a bit broad. Worse, climate is ENORMOUSLY complex and there are a lot of questions about it on this site, including our [list of worldbuilding resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/143607/40609). Have you reviewed those questions? If so, why have they not answered your Q? (Please [edit](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/181734/edit) your Q with your insights.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's very Earth similar with the same axial tilt and same orbit around the same luminosity Star as the Sun, then I would suggest googling all of the climatic zones to see where they occur on Earth and their longitude limits. For example the Mediterranean zone is unlikely to exist below 45 degrees South and is unlikely to exist over such a wide continental size area away from the sea.

If it deviates from Earth similar in any significant way then we need to know how it deviates.

Comment: Thank you. I understand and the colours were a little confusing (please the the updated image and ignore the grayed continents), which are just placeholders at the moment. for know I am assuming an earth clone, orbiting an earth-like sun.